# Send values to Python coroutine without handling StopIteration

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

Given a Python coroutine:

```
def coroutine():
     score = 0
     for _ in range(3):
          score = yield score + 1
```

I'd like to use it in a simple loop like this:

```
cs = coroutine()
for c in cs:
     print(c)
     cs.send(c + 1)
```

... which I would expect to print

```
1
3
5
```

But actually, I get an exception on the line `yield score + 1`:

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I can get it to work if I call `next` manually:

```
c = next(cs)
while True:
    print(c)
    try:
        c = cs.send(c + 1)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

But I don't like that I need to use try/except, given that generators are usually so elegant.

So, is there any way to use a finite coroutine like this without explicitly handling `StopIteration`? I'm happy to change both the generator and the way I'm iterating over it.

### Second Attempt

Martijn points out that both the `for` loop and my call to `send` advance the iterator. Fair enough. Why, then, can't I get around that with two yield statements in the coroutine's loop?

```
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    for _ in range(3):
        yield score
        score = yield score + 1

cs = coroutine()
for c in cs:
    print(c)
    cs.send(c + 1)
```

If I try that, I get the same error but on the `send` line.

```
0
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../coroutine_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    cs.send(c + 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: `for`-looping over a coroutine doesn't really make sense. The way you interact with a coroutine is completely different from the normal mode of interaction with an ordinary generator.

Comment: `yield score + 1` returns `None` and assigns that to `score`, so the next iteration attempts to add 1 to `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a stab at your second attempt. First, let `coroutine` be defined as:

```
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    for _ in range(3):
        yield
        score = yield score + 1
```

This function will output your `1, 3, 5` as in the original question.

Now, let's convert the `for` loop into a `while` loop.

```
# for loop
for c in cs:
    print(c)
    cs.send(c + 1)

# while loop
while True:
    try:
        c = cs.send(None)
        print(c)
        cs.send(c + 1)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Now, we can get this `while` loop working using the following if we precede it with a `next(cs)`. In total:

```
cs = coroutine()
next(cs)
while True:
    try:
        c = cs.send(None)
        print(c)
        cs.send(c + 1)
    except StopIteration:
        break
# Output: 1, 3, 5
```

When we try to convert this back into a for loop, we have the relatively simple code:

```
cs = coroutine()
next(cs)
for c in cs:
    print(c)
    cs.send(c + 1)
```

And this outputs the `1, 3, 5` as you wanted. The issue is that in the last iteration of the `for` loop, `cs` is already exhausted, but `send` is called again. So, how do we get another `yield` out of the generator? Let's add one to the end...

```
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    for _ in range(3):
        yield
        score = yield score + 1
    yield

cs = coroutine()
next(cs)
for c in cs:
    print(c)
    cs.send(c + 1)
# Output: 1, 3, 5
```

This final example iterates as intended without a `StopIteration` exception.

Now, if we take a step back, this can all be better written as:

```
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    for _ in range(3):
        score = yield score + 1
        yield # the only difference from your first attempt

cs = coroutine()
for c in cs:
    print(c)
    cs.send(c + 1)
# Output: 1, 3, 5
```

Notice how the `yield` moved, and the `next(cs)` was removed.

Comment: Very interesting! Your conversion of the `for` loop to a `while` loop is an eye-opener.

Comment: @z0r, check out the final update, moving the `yield` to the end makes everything a lot cleaner.

Comment: Yes, funny how the `yield` statements were around the wrong way! I still need to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with coroutines you generally have to use a `next()` call first to 'prime' the generator; it'll cause the generator function to execute code until the first `yield`. Your issue is mostly that you are using a `for` loop, however, which uses `next()` *as well*, but doesn't send anything.

You could add an extra `yield` to the coroutine to catch that first priming step, and add the `@consumer` decorator from [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) (adjusted for Python 2 and 3):

```
def consumer(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kw):
        gen = func(*args, **kw)
        next(gen)
        return gen
    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    wrapper.__dict__ = func.__dict__
    wrapper.__doc__  = func.__doc__
    return wrapper

@consumer
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    yield
    for _ in range(3):
        score = yield score + 1
```

You'd still have to use a `while` loop, as a `for` loop can't send:

```
c = 0
while True:
    try:
        c = cs.send(c + 1)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(c)
```

Now, if you want this to work with a `for` loop, you have to understand when the `next()` call from the `for` loop comes in when you are *in* the loop. When the `.send()` resumes the generator, the `yield` expression *returns the sent value*, and the generator continues on from there. So the generator function only stops again the *next* time a `yield` appears.

So looking at a loop like this:

```
for _ in range(3):
    score = yield score + 1
```

the first time you use `send` the above code has already executed `yield score + 1` and that'll now return the sent value, assigning it to `score`. The `for` loop continues on and takes the next value in the `range(3)`, starts another iteration, then executes `yield score + 1` again and pauses at that point. It is that *next iteration value* that is then produced.

Now, if you want to combine sending with plain `next()` iteration, you *can* add extra `yield` expressions, but those then need to be positioned such that your code is paused in the right locations; at a plain `yield value` when you are going to call `next()` (because it'll return `None`) and at a `target = yield` when you are using `generator.send()` (because it'll return the sent value):

```
@consumer
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    yield  # 1
    for _ in range(3):
        score = yield score + 1  # 2
        yield  # 3
```

When you use the above '@consumer' decorated generator with a `for` loop, the following happens:

- the `@consumer` decorator 'primes' the generator by moving to point 1.
- the `for` loop calls `next()` on the generator, and it advances to point 2, producing the `score + 1` value.
- a `generator.send()` call returns paused generator at point 2, assigning the sent value to `score`, and advances the generator to point 3. This *returns `None`* as the `generator.send()` result!
- the `for` loop calls `next()` again, advancing to point 2, giving the loop the next `score + 1` value.
- and so on.

So the above works directly with your loop:

```
>>> @consumer
... def coroutine():
...     score = 0
...     yield  # 1
...     for _ in range(3):
...         score = yield score + 1  # 2
...         yield  # 3
...
>>> cs = coroutine()
>>> for c in cs:
...     print(c)
...     cs.send(c + 1)
...
1
3
5
```

Note that the `@consumer` decorator and the first `yield` can now go again; the `for` loop can do that advancing to point 2 all by itself:

```
def coroutine():
    score = 0
    for _ in range(3):
        score = yield score + 1  # 2, for advances to here
        yield  # 3, send advances to here
```

and this still continues to work with your loop:

```
>>> def coroutine():
...     score = 0
...     for _ in range(3):
...         score = yield score + 1  # 2, for advances to here
...         yield  # 3, send advances to here
...
>>> cs = coroutine()
>>> for c in cs:
...     print(c)
...     cs.send(c + 1)
...
1
3
5
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that `functools.wraps` will do the double-under assignments for you.

Comment: Thanks! So why can't I just use two `yield` statements in the coroutine - one for the `for` loop, and one for `send`? I've added another example to my question.

Comment: @z0r: sorry, I ran out of time last night. I've added more info this morning.